# Specify a div with width:100% and some padding?

Tags: css, html

Basically I have a div with this CSS:

```
.mydiv{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    padding:7px;   
}​
```

The browser shows the horizontal due to padding (width 100% + 7px)
Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/3FrLq/

How can I have that div not showing the horizontal bar? (Without having to add another div inside?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the `width:auto` and replace it with `right:0`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3FrLq/1/)**

Since your element is positioned absolutely, you can in effect pull the left and right sides to the edges of the element's container without invoking the scrollbar.

Answer (score 2):

Correct HTML semantics pretty much requires that you have another element inside. In this case, your text should be wrapped in `<p>` tags.

Doing that automatically gives you something to hook into to set `margin` or `padding` on the inner element.

That said, if you *really* can't/won't have an inner element, remove your `width` and set `right: 0`. The nifty thing about absolutely positioned elements is that if you set opposing positions to 0, you can "stretch" the element (it works with top/bottom, too).

Alternatively, if your element isn't positioned absolutely, you can change your `width: 100%` to `max-width: 100%` (or add the `max-width` line, to deal with a bug in an old version of IE, if you have to go back that far), which will hard-cap the total width. This one's in action here - http://jsfiddle.net/3FrLq/5/ .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the box-sizing: border-box CSS property which will exclude the padding and borders from the actual width and height of the element:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border -box;
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3FrLq/3/

More info / browser support for box-sizing:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: That's nice... I really hate the box model. I hope one day browser will set width with the value of width really

Answer (score 1):

You can set the div to display `inline-block`:

```
.mydiv{
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    padding:7px;   
}​
```

This will display it inline (not stretching horizontally), while allowing you to still apply padding and margins to the top and bottom (unlike `display: inline`

Comment: ah, I misunderstood, you meant horizontal _scrollbar_

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of width specifying & just specify `0px`; for all 4 sides

Answer (score 1):

- if IE8+ compatibility enough for you, you can use [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing).
- if you want it to be working only with full width, set both `left` & `right` to `0`, but do not set a `width`.